# in Rails how to select additional columns from multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have these associations to describe a model where there is a list of Tags in the application (gardening, tutoring etc.. ) and a User will have 1 or more of these.  My best guess is the associations below

**User**

> has_many :**usertags**
>
> has_many :**tags**, through: :**usertags**

**Tag**

> has_many :**user** tags
>
> has_many :**users**, through: :**usertags**

**Usertag**

> belongs_to :**user**
>
> belongs_to :**tag**

I added the columns for user_id and tag_id to Usertag. I can setup the data and retrieve the list of tags for a user via

User.first.usertags for example.

How do I retrieve the Tag.name, User.id, and Usertag.id properties,  I tried this format

```
User.first.usertags.joins(:tag).select("tags.name, tags.id, usertags.id, user.id")
```

in my result all I see is

```
[#<Usertag id:1>, #<Usertag id:3>]>
```

Many thanks!

Comment: why do you want Usertag.id ?

Comment: Basically all I need is the Tags.name column to be in the result along with the Usertag info. As you can see I haven't got it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
result = User.first.usertags.joins(:tag).select("tags.name as tag_name, tags.id, usertags.id, user.id")

result.collect{|r| r.tag_name}
```